# Change Awesome CV layout

Tags: formatting, awesome-cv

I'm using `awesome-cv.cls` and it's amazing. However, one thing that I want would be to change the job title to be beside the company name as well as the date to be beside location. In my attached screenshot for example, would it be possible to make it be

```
TD Bank | SOLUTIONS DEVELOPER & DEVELOPMENT LEAD
```

and

```
May 2017-Sept 2017 | Toronto, ON
```

(while maintaining their respective style). What I mean would be to align them horizontally, instead of vertically. I looked at `awesome-cv.cls` and noticed that I should change cv information. However, I was not sure how to actually modify it.

This is the code seen there.

```
% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[5]{
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{12.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} \\
      \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
    \multicolumn{2}{L{17cm}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}} \\
  \end{tabular*}
}
```

And this is the minimal starting code

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[]{awesome-cv}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\fontdir[fonts/]
\newcommand*{\sectiondir}{resume/}

\definecolor{text}{HTML}{000000}
\begin{document}
\begin{cventries}
    \cventry
    {Solutions Developer \& Development Lead}
    {TD Bank}
    {Toronto, ON}
    {May 2017 – Sept 2017}
    {\begin{cvitems}
            \item {TEST}
    \end{cvitems}}
\end{cventries}
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting cv]

Comment: Could you please add a minimal but complete example document to work with?

Comment: I have added a minimal complete document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to redefine command `\cventry` or better to define a new command `\mycventry` like this (see the line marked with `<=====`):

```
% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\mycventry}[5]{%
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{12.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} | \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} | \entrydatestyle{#4}\\ % <================================================================
      }
    \multicolumn{2}{L{17cm}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}} \\
  \end{tabular*}
}
```

With the following complete code

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv}

%\usepackage{multicol}
\geometry{%
  showframe,
  left=2cm, top=1.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, footskip=.5cm
} % Configure page margins with geometry
\usepackage{graphicx}
\fontdir[fonts/] % Specify the location of the included fonts
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{parallel}


% Color for highlights
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-skyblue} % Default colors include: awesome-emerald, awesome-skyblue, awesome-red, awesome-pink, awesome-orange, awesome-nephritis, awesome-concrete, awesome-darknight
\colorlet{emphasis}{black}
\colorlet{body}{black!80!white}
%\definecolor{awesome}{HTML}{CA63A8} % Uncomment if you would like to specify your own color

\renewcommand{\acvHeaderSocialSep}{\quad\textbar\quad} % If you would like to change the social information separator from a pipe (|) to something else

% Define an entry of cv information
% Usage: \cventry{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}{<description>}
\newcommand*{\mycventry}[5]{%
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} L{12.5cm} R{4.5cm}}
    \ifempty{#2#3}
      {\entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrydatestyle{#4} \\}
      {\entrytitlestyle{#2} | \entrypositionstyle{#1} & \entrylocationstyle{#3} | \entrydatestyle{#4}\\ % <================================================================
      }
    \multicolumn{2}{L{17cm}}{\descriptionstyle{#5}} \\
  \end{tabular*}
}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PERSONAL INFORMATION
%   Comment any of the lines below if they are not required
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\name{James}{Bond}
\mobile{(+01) 234 56789}

\email{test@example.com}

\makecvfooter{\today}{James Bond~~~--~~~Curriculum Vitae}{\thepage}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\makecvheader % Print the header

\cvsection{Education}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CONTENT
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{cventries}

\mycventry % <==========================================================
{B.S. in Management Information Systems} % Degree
{Iowa State University} % Institution
{Ames, Iowa} % Location
{August 2014 - May 2018} % Date(s)
{}

\end{cventries}

\cvsection{Education}

\begin{cventries}

\mycventry % <==========================================================
{Something} % Degree
{Highschool} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}

\cventry
{Something} % Degree
{Highschool} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}

\cventry
{Something else} % Degree
{University} % Institution
{Springfield} % Location
{2025} % Date(s)
{ % Description(s) bullet points
\begin{cvitems}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\item {Test, Test, Test}
\end{cvitems}
}

\end{cventries}

\end{document}
```

you get then the result:

[image: result]

Please see that I only used the new command `\mycventry` for the first two entrys, marked with red arrows.